# como eliminar los pins del mapa?

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion multiplataforma en xamarin con google maps, para comenzar usé el siguiente sample de xamarin.

[Sample custom renderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/customized-pin/#Customizing_the_Info_Window)

Lo unico que le he agregado a ese ejemplo es que los valores de los pins se los doy dinamicamente en un foreach sacando los valores de un webservice, lo demas esta todo exactamente igual al ejemplo, todo funciona bien hasta ahi.

Ahora necesito implementar un boton para sacar todos los pines del mapa, estoy hace una semana probando distintas formas y no lo logro, lo que necesito en realidad es actualizar los pines pero para actualizarlos necesito eliminarlos primero.

Lo que pasa luego de presionar el boton se mantienen los pines en la pantalla pero al presionar uno de los pines se produce un nullreference exception, por lo tanto pienso que efectivamente se eliminan de la lista pero no de la vista.

El codigo de mi boton es el siguiente.

```
bActualizar.Clicked += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < customMap.Pins.Count; x++)
            {
                customMap.Pins.RemoveAt(x);
                customMap.Pins.Remove(customMap.Pins[x]);
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < customMap.CustomPins.Count; x++)
            {
                customMap.CustomPins.RemoveAt(x);
                customMap.CustomPins.Remove(customMap.CustomPins[x]);
            }

        };
```

Comment: Podrias intentar eliminarlos en un método no asíncrono?

Comment: lo hice no asincrono y no funcionó